# Countably monotone does not imply monotone and countably additive?

Tags: real-analysis

I just need a counterexample for this one.  As understand, it weakens the monotone and countably additive conditions for measure and creating outer measure but Royden doesn't like examples too much.

Also here are the definitions: If $\mu$ is a set function on a set X,  $\mu : S \rightarrow [0,\infty]$, S is a collection of subsets of X.

monotone:$A,B\in S$ if $A \subseteq B$ implies $\mu(A) \leq \mu(B);$

countably additive: $A_n\in S$ $\mu \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$.

countably monotone: If $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, then $\mu (A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$

The definitions are not that hard but I'm having trouble when I try to apply and think concretely.  I'm wondering if there is a space where measure fails but this generalization of measure works.

Comment: You're looking for a set function which is countably subadditive but not countably additive?  Try Lebesgue outer measure on the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$.  It's countably subadditive but is not countably additive (in general).

Comment: OK thanks.  I'll review those chapters... and I'll replace measure with set function.