# How do i prove that "countably monotone + Finitely Additive" implies "Premeasure" on a semiring?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $S$ be a semi-ring of subsets of $X$
>
> Let $\mu:S \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a set function on $X$
>
> If $\mu$ is countably monotone and finitely additive, then $\mu$ is a premeasure.

I know that this must be true, since $\mu$ can be extended to $\mu^*$ on a ring generated by $S$ which is countably monotone and finitely additive.

However, i don't know how to prove this directly.

Help..

Answer (score 2):

I'm the OP and since i have a low bounty, i cannot comment on Karene's question, so i'm writing this as an answer. The set $S$ Karene constructed is not a semi-ring on $X$. Since $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{a\}$ cannot be a *finite* union of elements of $S$.

I have proved the following:

> Let $X$ be a set.
>
> Let $S$ be a semi-ring on $X$.
>
> Let $\mu:S\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
>
> Then, $\mu$ is countably additive if and only if it is countably monotone and finitely additive.

The proof for *if* part does not require any choice, but the proof for *only if* part requires choice.

The key idea for the proof is that $\{A\subset X: A \text{ is a finite disjoint union of elements in } S\}$ is indeed a ring on $X$.

Finite additivity makes it possible to construct a function $\mu^*$ on this ring such that $\mu^* (A) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i)$ whenever $A$ is a disjoint union of a finite sequence $A_i$ in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition I was given:

Definitions:

*Semi-ring:* [From Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets)

*Countably monotone:* [From this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338433/countably-monotone-does-not-imply-monotone-and-countably-additive)

*Pre-measure:* From the comment of user Number9 below.

**Example:** Then consider the set $\mathbb{N}$, the collection $S$ of sets $\emptyset$ together with all the singleton subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{N}$.

Define $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, $\mu(\{a\})=1/2^a$, and $\mu(\mathbb{N})=1$.

We have that $S$ is a semi-ring: It contains the emptyset, intersections of any two sets in $S$ is the emptyset, and differences of any two sets are in there.

We  have that $\mu(\mathbb{N})=1<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu(\{n\})=1+1/2+1/2^2+...=2$

Finite additivity is trivially satisfied because the only finite disjoint unions of elements of $S$ that are also in $S$ are finite unions like $\emptyset\cup\{a\}$ or $\emptyset\cup\mathbb{N}$.

The issue is being that since finite additivity is being satisfied trivially, it is not forcing $\mu(\mathbb{N})$ up from the monotonicity that follows from finite additivity.

Can we consider then $\mu$ defined on a ring of sets?

Comment: Since the domain is a semiring, $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)$ is not defined.

Comment: Just a minute. Still editing.

Comment: @Number9 But the definition of premeasure requires defining it on a ring of sets. Do you mean extends to a premeasure?

Comment: No. Let $X$ be a set and $F$ be a collection of subsets of $X$. Then, a premeasure $\mu$ on $F$ is a set function such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ if $\emptyset \in F$ and $\mu(\bigcup A_n) = \sum \mu(A_n)$ if $\{A_n\}$ is a disjoint sequence in $F$ and $\bigcup A_n \in F$.

Comment: There is a theorem that "A Countably monotone & finitely additive set function on a semi-ring $S$ can be uniquely extended to a countably monotone & finitely additive set function on a ring generated by $S$. So the statement in my post must be true. But since the proof for the theorem is a bit complicated and it requires "Axiom of Countable choice", i'm looking for some direct proof.

Comment: Please check the hypothesis for "Hahn-Kolmogorov Theorem" in wikipedia for the definition of pre-measure.

Comment: @Number9 The definition in Wikipedia of a pre-measure is given on a ring of sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premeasure#Definition) But I guess I could see what follows from the definition you are giveng above.

Comment: @Number9 OK, from the definitions given I think it is false. Let me add the example to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the direct proof the OP sought.

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ be disjoint sets in the $S$. Let $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in S$. By countable monotonicity (or even countable subadditivity), we have 
$$
\mu(A) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i). 
$$
Now we prove the other direction.
By induction, we can write 
$$
A \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \left( A \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i \right) \setminus A_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^{m_n} D_{i,n}
$$
where $D_{1,n},\ldots,D_{m_n,n}$ are disjoint sets in $S$. Moreover, each $D_{1,n},\ldots,D_{m_n,n}$ is disjoint from each $A_1,\ldots,A_n$. Thus the sets $D_{1,n},\ldots,D_{m_n,n},A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are disjoint sets in $S$. Also
$$
A = \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{m_n} D_{i,n} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}  A_i \right).  
$$
Therefore finite additivity gives 
$$
\mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} \mu(D_{i,n}) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(A_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(A_i).  
$$
Letting $n \to \infty$ gives the desired result.