# If a set function on a semiring is finitely additive and continuous at the empty set, then is it necessarily a premeasure (i.e., countably additive)?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semiring on a set $X$. This means that $\mathcal{S}$ contains $\emptyset$, is closed under intersections, and every relative complement of two sets in $\mathcal{S}$ is a disjoint union of finitely many sets in $\mathcal{S}$.

Let $\mu:\mathcal{S} \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Some terminology:

Saying $\mu$ is finitely additive means that if $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ belong to $\mathcal{S}$ and are disjoint, and if $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$, then $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu(A_i)$.

Saying $\mu$ is countably additive means that if the $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ belong to $\mathcal{S}$ and are disjoint, and if $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$, then $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i)$. If $\mu$ is countably additive, it is called a premeasure.

Saying $\mu$ is continuous at $\emptyset$ means that if $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ is a decreasing sequence of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \emptyset$, then $\lim_{i \to \infty} \mu(A_i) = 0$.

**Question**

Prove or disprove the following statement.

(Q): If $\mu(A)$ is finite for all $A$ in $\mathcal{S}$, if $\mu$ is finitely additive, and if $\mu$ is continuous at $\emptyset$, then $\mu$ is countably additive.

**Remark**

If $\mathcal{S}$ is a ring (so that it is closed under relative complements), rather than a semi-ring, then (Q) is true and the proof is fairly easy. Ineed, it can found in many textbooks, such as those by Bauer, by Cohn, by Klenke, and by Yeh).

**Related**

[How do i prove that "countably monotone + Finitely Additive" implies "Premeasure" on a semiring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629248/how-do-i-prove-that-countably-monotone-finitely-additive-implies-premeasure/3491694#3491694)

Comment: You have a typo in the definition of "continuous at $\emptyset$".

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Not fixed... should be $\bigcap$ instead of $\bigcup$.

Comment: @WhatsUp You can fix obvious typos yourself, as I have.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ah yes... still not used to this privilege (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, perhaps somewhat surprisingly, false.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the semiring of rational intervals with rational endpoints.  More precisely, a member of $\mathcal{S}$ is of the form
$$
I\cap \mathbb{Q}
$$
where $I$ is some interval with rational endpoints.

Let 
$$
\mu(I\cap\mathbb{Q})=m(I)
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure (i.e. length).

This function is finitely additive, continuous at $\emptyset$, but not countably additive. Indeed, 
$$
\mu(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])=1\neq 0=\sum_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}\mu(\{q\})
$$

Comment: Could you please give an example of a sequence on which it is not countably additive?

Comment: @JasonJones Done

Comment: Notably, this function is continuous from below as well. So replacing continuity at $\emptyset$ by continuity from below does not save the statement. Wonderful.

Comment: @JasonJones and continuous from above too :)

Comment: Sorry for this. But I just had a doubt. How is $\{q\}$ a set of the form $\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: a \leq q < b\}$?

Comment: @JasonJones Hmm, you're right. I added an edit, I think that should fix it. Sorry about that!